# Supertype/subtype db design with subtype cross-link

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

This is probably a simple problem for an experienced database developer, but I'm struggling... I have trouble translating a certain ER diagram to a DB model, any help is appreciated.

I have a setup similar to slide 17 of this presentation:
http://www.cbe.wwu.edu/misclasses/mis421s04/presentations/supersubtype.ppt

Slide 17 shows an ER diagram with an Employee supertype having an Employee Type attribute and as subtypes the Employee Types themselves (Hourly, Salaried and Consultant), which is very similar to my design situation.

In my case, suppose Salaried Employees are the only ones that can be bosses of other employees and I wanted to somehow indicate if a certain Salaried employee is the boss of the Hourly and/or Salaried Employee and/or Consultant (either, none or both), how could that be designed in a database model, also considering these are one-to-many relationships?

I can put a PK-FK relationship between them, which would result in all tables having two FKeys and (like Consultant having FK_Employee and FK_SalariedEmployee) and SalariedEmployee referencing itself, but I keep thinking that might not be the wisest solution....although I'm not sure why (integrity issues?).

Is this or an acceptable solution or is there a better one?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case looks like an instance of the design pattern known as “Generalization Specialization” (Gen-Spec for short).  The gen-spec pattern is familiar to object oriented programmers.  It’s covered in tutorials when teaching about inheritance and subclasses.

The design of SQL tables that implement the gen-spec pattern can be a little tricky.  Database design tutorials often gloss over this topic.  But it comes up again and again in practice.

If you search the web on “generalization specialization relational modeling” you’ll find several useful articles that teach you how to do this.  You’ll also be pointed to several times this topic has come up before in this forum.

The articles generally show you how to design a single table to capture all the generalized data and one specialized table for each subclass that will contain all the data specific to that subclass.  The interesting part involves the primary  key for the subclass tables.  You won’t use the autonumber feature of the DBMS to populate the sub class primary key.  Instead, you’ll program the application to propagate the primary key value obtained for the generalized table to the appropriate subclass table.

This creates a two way association between the generalized data and the specialized data.  A simple view for each specialized subclass will collect generalized and specialized data together.  It’s easy once you get the hang of it, and it performs fairly well.

In your specific case, declaring the "boss of" FK to reference the PK in the Salaried Employees table will be enough to do the trick.  This will produce the two way association you want, and also prevent employees who are not salaried from being referenced as bosses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I get it, but to check for sure: The PK id for the gen table (Employee) would in fact be made the same as the PK id for one of the the spec table programmatically? So each spec table (subtype) would always have different PK ids related to a single gen row. This would mean the 'boss of' FK can also always be related to the gen table (supertype). Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: eh... I meant the other way around of course... The PK id for the spec table (e.g. Salaried Employee) would in fact be made the same as the PK id for one of the the gen table (Employee) programmatically, right?

Comment: Yes, and more.  The FK for the "Boss of column" would be the same value as the PK of one row in the Salaried Employees table.  This PK in turn would be the same value as the value of the PK in one row of the gen Employees table.  So you can join all three tables based on this common value.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much! This solves the problem I'm tackling PERFECTLY.